# Classifying time periods in new field using Python Parser of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, datetime, if-else

I have a datetime field *(Horario)* in my feature class, showing only the time. Although the date doesn't appear, it seem to be stored automatically as 30 Dec 1899, I'm not sure why.

I want to use this field to populate another field *(Periodo)* , where I'll have different periods of the day: morning (6 am - 12pm), afternoon (12pm - 6pm), evening (6pm - 12am) and night (12am - 6am).

I'm trying to write an if-elif statement on the Field Calculator, but I'm always having an "invalid syntax" error, and I'm guessing that's because of the datetime expression I'm using. Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
def Reclass(horario):
    if (horario < date '1899-12-30 12:00:00' and horario >= date '1899-12-30 06:00:00'):
        return "Manhã (6-12h)"
    elif (horario < date '1899-12-30 18:00:00' and horario >= date '1899-12-30 12:00:00'):
        return "Tarde (12-18h)"
    elif (horario <= date '1899-12-30 23:59:00' and horario >= date '1899-12-30 18:00:00'):
        return "Noite (18-24h)"
    elif (horario < date '1899-12-30 06:00:00' and horario >= date '1899-12-30 00:00:00'):
        return "Madrugada (0-6h)"

Reclass(!Horário!)
```

I'm thinking the problem is I'm referring to the date as

```
date '1899-12-30 06:00:00'
```

**How should I refer to datetime fields when using Python?**

[image: that's how my table looks like]

Comment: what is the type of field for horario / actual values in your attributes?

Comment: The type is date, the actual values are shown like _09:10:00_, for instance, but when I do a SQL Query, it appears as _date '1899-12-30 09:10:00'_. I think that's why I'm getting confuse, I don't know how the actual values are being stored.

Comment: Well, `AND` is not a valid python keyword, so you'll always get an invalid syntax error.

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks so much Paul! Unfortunately, that was not the only problem, I'm still getting a sintax error...

Answer (score 5):

Using cursors is a good way to inspect how datetime fields can be accessed and written to. This is taken from a feature class, with a a date field:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("poly_small", ("COL_DATE")) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
        print row[0], type(row[0])
```

---

```
2014-07-18 06:03:05 <type 'datetime.datetime'>
2014-07-17 00:00:00 <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

So, the easiest way to build this would be with the `datetime` module.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt    
test = dt(2014, 7, 18, 6, 3, 5)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("poly_small", ("COL_DATE")) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
        print row[0], type(row[0]), row[0] == test
```

---

```
2014-07-18 06:03:05 <type 'datetime.datetime'> True
2014-07-17 00:00:00 <type 'datetime.datetime'> False
```

Instead of using `and`, there is a simpler way to check if a number lies between two numbers see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) I believe the following is correct:

```
def Reclass(horario):

    if dt(1899,12,30, 12,0,0) > horario  >= dt(1899,12,30, 6,0,0):
        return "Manhã (6-12h)"

    elif dt(1899,12,30, 18,0,0) > horario >= dt(1899,12,30, 12,0,0):
        return "Tarde (12-18h)"

    elif dt(1899,12,30, 23,59,0) >= horario >= dt(1899,12,30, 18,0,0):
        return "Noite (18-24h)"

    elif dt(1899,12,30, 6,0,0) > horario >= dt(1899,12,30, 0,0,0):
        return "Madrugada (0-6h)"
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, Paul! Thanks for the throughout answer! It's really helping me understand how to use date with python. I used the code as shown, but I get the error 
_File "<expression>", line 1, in <module> 
File "<string>", line 4, in Reclass 
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode_

It's weird, because the only string I have it's after _return_. Any guess?

Comment: @Beatriz Viseu, `horario` is in unicode, likely.

Comment: Yeah, so I changed my code to the '1899-12-30 06:00:00' style, and it's now comparable. It even worked with a simpler code _(if horario > '1899-12-30 06:00:00': return "Manhã")_. However, it doesn't seem to like when I use multiple statements (horario>x and horario<y / x>horario>y). I tried both ways, the tool does run, I don't get any error, but all my records keep as <Null>. I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: @BeatrizViseu, So you aren't using the `datetime` module at all? You might want to update your question with the new code or start another one if you have a different question entirely.